# true false questions on Extension Fields

Tags: abstract-algebra

which of the following statements are true?

1. $\mathbb{Q}$ is an extension field of $\mathbb{Z}_2$.
2. Let $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ be algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$ of degree $n$. If $f(\alpha) = 0$ for nonzero $f(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$, then 
   $( degree f(x)) \geq n$.
3. Let $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ be algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$ of degree $n$. If $f(\alpha) = 0$ for nonzero $f(x) \in \mathbb{R}[x]$, then 
   $( degree f(x)) \geq n$.
4. If $x$ is an indeterminate, $\mathbb{Q}[\pi]$ ~ $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.

---

my thoughts:-

1. false as $x^2+1$ has a solution in $\mathbb{Z}_2$ but not in $\mathbb{Q}$
2. I guess it is true but not sure.
3. similar to 2 but not sure again.
4. no idea.

does my thoughts are true for 1.
and can anyone help me for the others.
thanks for your help.

Comment: What is the degree of $\alpha$? Is it the degre of its minimal polynomial?

Comment: yes,of course..

Comment: 2 is true, 3 is not true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct for number $1$. Your way is fine, but this is really a problem about the characteristics of the fields involved. If $\mathbb Q$ were an extension field of $\mathbb Z_2$, there would be an injection from the latter to the former. But for any such injection $\phi$, $0=\phi(0)=\phi(2)=\phi(1+1)=1+1=2$, a contradiction.

Number $2$ is true. To prove it, recall basic properties of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$. However, $3$ is false. There are many counterexamples, and $\alpha=\sqrt 2$ is one of them. I encourage you to work out the details.

Number 4 is true. Consider the homomorphism from $\mathbb Q[x]$ to $\mathbb Q[\pi]$ that sends x to π. The kernel is trivial because π is transcendental, and it is clearly surjective.